# Using \alpha in my nomenclature using \usepackage{acronym}

Tags: acronyms, greek, nomenclature

I have to add the greek symbol \alpha to my nomenclature. I am using \usepackage{acronym}. However, I keep getting errors when compiling.

My nomenclature:

```
\begin{acronym}[MPC]
\acro{\alpha}[\alpha]{conversion coefficient}
\end{acronym}
```

My Preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}\includepdf[pages={x-y}]{fil.pdf}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{eurosym}
```

Hope you can help me with this very annoying problem.

Comment: Quite likely `\acro{alpha}[\ensuremath{\alpha}]{conversion coefficient}`. The first argument should not be a control sequence, but just a (unique) string of characters.

Comment: I tried using \acro{alpha}[\ensuremath{\alpha}]{conversion coefficient}, but I get this error: 

The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

Comment: No, that's not possible, see my answer. Your attempt probably had `\acro{\alpha}[...]{...}`

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `\acro` should be a string of characters, not a command. Since `\alpha` is a math command, you need to ensure math mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\includepdf[pages={x-y}]{fil.pdf}% not in the preamble!
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}[MPC]
\acro{alpha}[\ensuremath{\alpha}]{conversion coefficient}
\end{acronym}


1. \ac{alpha} [first appearance]

2. \ac{alpha} [second appearance]

3. \acl{alpha} [long form]

4. \acf{alpha} [full form]

\end{document}
```

[image]