# Accents with the acronym package

Tags: acronyms, accents

Is there any way to use accents with the acronym package? I need to write the following acronym \ac{{Mónashell}}, but that does not work, nor does \ac{{M\´onashell}}, and the package documentation does not seem to include accents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\begin{document}
frontmatter
\begin{acronym}[Sulfiloggerrrrrrrr]
\acro{M\´onashell}{seashell media biofiltration system from Bord na M\´ona}
\acro{WWTP}{wastewater treatment plant}
\acro{H2S}[\ce{H_{2}S}]{hydrogen sulphide}
\end{acronym}
\mainmatter
There are similarities between the observed removal of \ac{H2S} through biofiltration in this study and those described by \cite{Abraham2015}, who demonstrated a removal greater than 99 \% by the utilisation of the \ac{Mónashell} at Lake Wildwood \ac{WWTP}. 
\end{document}
```

[image: Acronym list]

[image: Test and one of the error messages]

Hope someone can help me with this problem :-)

Comment: What version of tex are you using? Can you give a full compilable example? This should just work using an accented character in any of the key, short, or long form of an acronym.

Comment: @DaiBowen, I have added the information in the original question.

Comment: Ok, that just work was for accented as in `ó` not `\'o`.  It's the same problem as [your earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/675379/106162), the acronym key needs to be a string, `\acro{ó}{óóó}` will work (as will `\acro{ó}{ó\'oo}`),  `\acro{\'o}{óóó}` will not.  The acronym will similarly need to be used as `\ac{ó}`, `\ac{\'o}` will not work.

Comment: @DaiBowen, you are amazing. Thanks a million! Will try to learn more about strings, so I will not have to get help for the same type of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid special characters in the acronym key, exactly like you do for `H2S`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\begin{acronym}[Sulfiloggerrrrrrrr]
\acro{MS}[M\'onashell]{seashell media biofiltration system from Bord na M\'ona}
\acro{WWTP}{wastewater treatment plant}
\acro{H2S}[\ce{H_{2}S}]{hydrogen sulphide}
\end{acronym}

\mainmatter

There are similarities between the observed removal of \ac{H2S} 
through biofiltration in this study and those described by 
\cite{Abraham2015}, who demonstrated a removal greater than 99\% 
by the utilisation of the \ac{MS} at Lake Wildwood \ac{WWTP}. 

There are similarities between the observed removal of \ac{H2S} 
through biofiltration in this study and those described by 
\cite{Abraham2015}, who demonstrated a removal greater than 99\% 
by the utilisation of the \ac{MS} at Lake Wildwood \ac{WWTP}. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]